# Asp.net custom ajax file uploader

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I develop custom file uploader.

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuUpload" />

<asp:UpdatePanel  runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CausesValidation="false"
            OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />

      <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red" /></div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAttachments" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Uploader_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <a href='<%#GetUrl(....) %>'><%#Eval("Filename") %></a> <b>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Удалить" CommandName="DeleteAttachment" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FileName") %>' /></b>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rptAttachments" EventName="ItemCommand" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>




 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {          
   //fuUpload.HasFile == false 
    if (fuUpload.HasFile && fuUpload.PostedFile != null 
        && fuUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
     { 
     }
  }
```

I wonder why `fuUpload.HasFile` always equls `null`.

Comment: naveen's solution is good. The reason for the full postback is that the fileupload does NOT work with asynchronous postbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these things.

1. Put `<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuUpload" />` **inside** `UpdatePanel`
2. Set `btnUpload` trigger like this. `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />`

Comment: It works with postback! Could I use fileUpload without postBack?

Comment: there are no simple methods to do so. but you can always use something like [jQuery Ajax uploader plugin](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/)